GDDR5 Clamshell mode impact for bandwidth
So we know that GDDR5 memory supports "clamshell mode", where two memory chips share a single 32-bit segment, effectively reducing their width to 16 bits each.
So, with clamshell mode Vram bandwidth is lower than in normal mode, or stays same ?
I mean 980 Ti uses 384 Bit Bus with 12 memory modules https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/geforce-gtx-980-ti.c2724
Titan X uses same 384 Bit but with 24 Modules, 12 modules is on opposite side https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/geforce-gtx-titan-x.c2632
And exist 660 Ti with unbalanced memory 1
And i correctly undertood that in situation with 660 Ti bandwidth is unstable (lower) in some part of memory because one controller work with more chips and capacity than others.
1st. Controller works with 512MB (2 chips)
2nd. Controller works with 512MB (2 chips)
3rd. Controller works with 1GB (4 chips)

I'm not seeing a question here. can you help us understand?
